# Wordpress how to use two variables for Post__not_in argument in a wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I put two variables in `post__not_in` like this:

```php
'post__not_in' => $excludeHome, $excludePostSlide
```

When I do this only posts from first variable don't show up from the others show up.

I can do that with array push like below but is there any different way to do it?

```
  @php
    wp_reset_postdata();
    global $excludeHome;
    global $excludePostSlide;
    array_push($excludeHome, $excludePostSlide[0], $excludePostSlide[1], $excludePostSlide[2], $excludePostSlide[3], $excludePostSlide[4], $excludePostSlide[5]);
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'category_name' => 'auto',
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'no_found_rows' => true,
        'post__not_in' => $excludeHome,
    ];
    $querySlider = new WP_Query($args);
  @endphp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [`wp_query`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters), `post__not_in` accepts an array of post ids.

- It's not clear that your global `$excludeHome` and `$excludePostSlide` variables are actually arrays. So make sure that they are arrays.
- In order to use `array_push` function, it's better to use a `foreach` loop on the `$excludePostSlide` array, rather than trying to push them by their index number!

```php
global $excludeHome;
global $excludePostSlide;

$excludeHome = is_array($excludeHome)
    ? $excludeHome
    : (array)$excludeHome;

$excludePostSlide = is_array($excludePostSlide)
    ? $excludePostSlide
    : (array)$excludePostSlide;

foreach ($excludePostSlide as $excludeSlide) {
    array_push($excludeHome, $excludeSlide);
}

$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'category_name'  => 'auto',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'no_found_rows'  => true,
    'post__not_in'   => $excludeHome,
];

$querySlider = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked, I use roots-sage and in order to use roots sage I use bedrock which is build with laravel blade, also roots-sage theme is build with laravel blade

Answer (score 0):

try to pass the parameter as `array` :

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'category_name' => 'auto',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'post__not_in' => array(
          $excludeHome, 
          $excludePostSlide
     )
];
$querySlider = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: I've tried but it is not working none of the posts gets excluded

Comment: It doesn't show any error or anything just it doesnt exclude the posts

Comment: Are the variables the category IDs? If so, that should work. I reference this query list to find all the various pieces in one place. https://github.com/luetkemj/wp-query-ref

Comment: Yes they are the ID of posts, as you can see `array_push($excludeHome, $excludePostSlide[0], $excludePostSlide[1], $excludePostSlide[2], $excludePostSlide[3], $excludePostSlide[4], $excludePostSlide[5]);` this piece of code works if i do it with array push but I don't know if it is the best practice